# Copy chart from excel sheet to placeholder in word template

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, ms-office

I thought that this would be a relative simple piece of code but is seems that it is a bit more challanging then I initially expected.

what I am trying to do is copy a chart (or charts) from the macro embeded excel sheet that I have, to a word template (.docx). I have broken down the code such that it runs with sub routines

though I keep on getting an error that I cant wrap my head around. After a bit of digging the code fails at the following line:

`wdApp.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile`

I dont understand what I am doing wrong, any ideas are welcome. my code is the following:

```
    Dim wdApp As Object
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim wordTemplatePath As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    ' Update the path of your Word template
    wordTemplatePath = "C:\ My file Path ...\...\Playground Template\test.docx"

    ' Create a new instance of Word and open the template
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(wordTemplatePath)


    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
           
        If ws.name = "Sheet1" Then
             Debug.Print ("in IF loop")
             CopyChart ws, wdDoc, wdApp, "Chart 2"
                      
        End If
    Next ws
    

    ' Save the Word template and close the Word application
    wdDoc.Save
    wdApp.Quit
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set wdApp = Nothing

    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink wordTemplatePath
    
End Sub



Sub CopyChart(ws As Worksheet, wdDoc As Object, wdApp As Object, chartName As String)

    Dim chartObj As ChartObject
    Dim wdPasteEnhancedMetafile As Long

    wdPasteEnhancedMetafile = 9 ' Define the constant value for enhanced metafile
      
        Set chartObj = ws.ChartObjects(chartName)
        chartObj.Copy
        
        wdDoc.Content.Find.Execute FindText:="ChartPlaceholder", ReplaceWith:="", Replace:=2
        wdApp.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

The error message I get is the following:

[image: Error message]

also when comparing the template with the produced word instance I can see that the "ChartPlaceholder" is left blank as instructed in line

`wdDoc.Content.Find.Execute FindText:="ChartPlaceholder", ReplaceWith:="", Replace:=2`

[image: comparison]

Answer (score 0):

Your code mentions a `Selection` that is not there. I guess you wanted to paste where the word to be replaced was to be found

(Adjusted to reproduce your example - with Word Object Library enabled )

```
Sub caLLPasteChartsToWord()
'
Dim xLAppL As Excel.Application: Set xLAppL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Dim wBTrgt As Excel.Workbook: Set wBTrgt = xLAppL.ActiveWorkbook
Dim wSTarget As Excel.Worksheet: Set wSTarget = xLAppL.Worksheets("Sheet4")



   Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim wordTemplatePath As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet


    xLAppL.ScreenUpdating = False


    ' Update the path of your Word template
    wordTemplatePath = "C:\ My file Path ...\...\Playground Template\test.docx"

    ' Create a new instance of Word and open the template
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.ActiveDocument '.Active.Documents.Open(wordTemplatePath)


    For Each ws In xLAppL.Worksheets 'wBTrgt 'ThisWorkbook.Sheets
           
        If ws.Name = "Sheet4" Then
             Debug.Print ("in IF loop")
             CopyChart ws, wdDoc, wdApp, "Chart 2"
                      
        End If
    Next ws
    

    ' Save the Word template and close the Word application
    wdDoc.Save
    wdApp.Quit
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set wdApp = Nothing

    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink wordTemplatePath
    
End Sub



Sub CopyChart(ws As Worksheet, wdDoc As Object, wdApp As Object, chartName As String)
Dim xLAppL As Excel.Application: Set xLAppL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    Dim chartObj As ChartObject
    Dim wdPasteEnhancedMetafile As Long
Dim whereToPaste As String: whereToPaste = "PasteHere"
    wdPasteEnhancedMetafile = 9 ' Define the constant value for enhanced metafile
      
        Set chartObj = ws.ChartObjects(chartName)
        chartObj.Copy
        
        wdDoc.Content.Find.Execute FindText:="ChartPlaceholder", ReplaceWith:="", Replace:=2
        wdDoc.Bookmarks.Add "PasteHere"
        Dim wdRng As Word.Range: Set wdRng = wdDoc.Bookmarks(whereToPaste).Range
        wdRng.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
          DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, Placement:=wdInLine
      wdDoc.Bookmarks(whereToPaste).Delete
'        wdApp.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile
        xLAppL.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

The important bit is where a `Bookmark` is added , to define a range in word where to paste.

```
Dim whereToPaste As String: whereToPaste = "PasteHere"

...

wdDoc.Bookmarks.Add "PasteHere"


...


Dim wdRng As Word.Range: Set wdRng = wdDoc.Bookmarks(whereToPaste).Range

...
'this is the part you needed: a range where to paste

wdRng.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
          DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, Placement:=wdInLine

... 'and finally delete the Bookmark so it can be added again if needed

      wdDoc.Bookmarks(whereToPaste).Delete
```

Comment: Thanks but the code doesnt seem to be running,

Comment: Is it showing some error? I have tested it and it pastes on target,`I am running it with an open document (hence the `GetObject`) , so you may have to edit that part